# как в php динамически указывать название объекта?

Tags: php, laravel

Как в цикле `isset($request->с_1)` вместо `с_1` использовать индекс цикла?

```
public function tovolunteer(Request $request){       
    for($i=1;$i<19;$i++){
      if(isset($request->с_1)){
          echo"yEs <br/>";
      } else {
          echo"not"; 
      }
      if(isset($request->с_2)){
          echo"yEs <br/>";
      } else{
          echo"not"; 
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Вы можете сделать `$request = (array) $request;` приведения к типу массива и уже вызывать через `$request['c_1']`. Или что вы подразумеваете, под индекс цикла? Это не понятно! Что вообще необходимо в результате получить? И почему бы просто не использовать `foreach` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (isset($request->{"c_1"})) ...` ну или же в вашем случае `if (isset($request->{"c_$i"})) ...`

Надеюсь я правильно понял вопрос?

Comment: @Николай, Мне просто интересно, зачем так делать, когда можно воспользоваться `foreach` и `substr` для проверки `c_` и уже от суда плясать. Этим мы сделаем 1 цикл и сразу же разбор всех `c_*`. Сейчас  у вас используется цикл на 19 элементов обязательно, а если сформируется по каким-то причинам 10, это будет 9 лишних итераций. Нужно как минимум тогда смотреть размер объекта и фильтровать только нужные свойства.

Comment: @And я ответил на конкретный вопрос автора. То что этот цикл не корректно написан это совсем другая история. А в целом согласен, `foreach` был бы больше здесь кстати. Но это понимание приходит с практикой. Новички в программировании не пытаются сделать правильно, красиво и оптимизировано а просто сделать чтобы хоть как-то работало.